# The plot curve goes under the X-axis - fix?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, plot

Why when I input the command `Plot[E^(-x), {x, 0, 2}]` in **Mathematica 8** the point `(2, e^(-2))` goes under the X-axis? How can I fix that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Plot[E^(-x), {x, 0, 2}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Heike's answer is just fine, but here's an alternative:

```
Plot[E^(-x), {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {0, Automatic}]
```